# Pass uintmax_t or size_t to custom printf conversion specifier

Tags: c, gcc, printf

I'm writing a conversion specifier (`%b`) to be able to print any unsigned integer type in binary.

Here is the full code of it: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/219994/register-b-conversion-specifier

Everything seems to work right now, but there's the possibility that

```
sizeof(uintmax_t) > sizeof(unsigned long long)
```

And the same with `size_t`

And glibc only seems to pass info about "normal" integer types (`unsigned` + length modifiers or `char`).  Is it just impossible right now to prepare for that?  Maybe because there is no implementation yet where those two types are wider (AFAIK).

How does glibc handle the `j` and `z` length modifiers? Probably they just are registered as equivalents to `ll`, and don't have a different handling.

**EDIT:**

There seems to be some hint that there may exist the possibility of handling types other than the basic ones.

From `<printf.h>`:

```
/* Type of a printf specifier-arginfo function.
 INFO gives information about the format specification.
 N, ARGTYPES, *SIZE has to contain the size of the parameter for
 user-defined types, and return value are as for parse_printf_format
 except that -1 should be returned if the handler cannot handle
 this case. This allows to partially overwrite the functionality
 of existing format specifiers. */

 typedef int printf_arginfo_size_function (const struct printf_info *__info,
                     size_t __n, int *__argtypes,
                     int *__size);
```

See `*SIZE` aka `int *__size`

And also another hint in the deprecated old functions:

```
/* Old version of 'printf_arginfo_function' without a SIZE parameter. */

 typedef int printf_arginfo_function (const struct printf_info *__info,
                 size_t __n, int *__argtypes);

/* Obsolete interface similar to register_printf_specifier. It can only
 handle basic data types because the ARGINFO callback does not return
 information on the size of the user-defined type. */

 extern int register_printf_function (int __spec, printf_function __func,
                 printf_arginfo_function __arginfo)
 __THROW __attribute_deprecated__;
```

Comment: The `glibc` library doesn't have to handle non-existent (hypothetical) situations — it only has to handle ones that it currently encounters on actual hardware.  It doesn't try to deal with the situation because it doesn't encounter it.  It is unlikely that `printf()` handles `__int128_t` types, even though the compiler may support them (partially).

Comment: Glibc is open source.  If you wan't to know details of how it does things, then [*look*](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf-internal.c;h=ead2b04cb96b0346dde876e5d41418fae2cc8b0d;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Are you asking about what type to use with va_arg and in your code? Presumably it uses va_arg(va, size_t) if you use 'z' and va_arg(va, uintmax_t) if you use 'j'. I'm not seeing the problem.

Comment: @immibis The problem is the information `printf` passes to my function when called with a `j` or `z`.

Comment: [This is a topic of hot contention at the moment](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2303.pdf); it's entirely possible `intmax_t` will be deprecated or dropped from C2x because of this kind of conflict, or at least re-scoped to avoid misleading developers into thinking it is useful for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it just impossible right now to prepare for that?

Yes.

`struct printf_info` in not prepared for handling an implementation where there are many true integer sizes.

Instead when a `j, z, t` modifier is used today, it maps as *none*, `l, ll` in some fashion.

Should `int128_t, int256_t, int512_t, int1024_t` come out, certainly  [`struct printf_info`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Conversion-Specifier-Options.html) will evolve.  It is just not known what that is today.